# ASP NET MVC 5 система рейтинга

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Хочу сделать систему рейтинга для постов(создание постов уже сделал) которые создают пользователи(и сортировку постов по рейтингу, и по "свежести")
Вот например есть идея сделать рейтинг через AJAX ASP.NET Rating Control
а что насчет сортировки?

Answer (score 3):

Допустим у вас есть класс `Post` и его поле `int Rating`

Сортировка средствами Linq EF делается так.

```
var postsList = db.Posts.OrderBy(x=>x.Rating);
```

То есть везде где вы можете применять Linq, для любого списка объектов, вы можете сортировать список используя функции `OrderBy` (сортировка) и `OrderByDescending` (сортировка в обратном порядке).

Отдельная таблица на голоса

```
public class Vote
{
    [Key]
    public int PostId {get;set;}
    public virtual Post Post {get;set;}
    [Key]
    public string UserId {get;set;}
    public virtual  User User {get;set;}
    public int Vote {get;set;} // значения от 1 до 10
}
```

При каждом голосе создаём новую запись Vote если её не было, или перезаписываем старую.
Замечаем что по одному посту один пользователь голосует только один раз, это уже есть в модели.
После создания или перезаписи Vote пересчитывает Post.Rating по формуле среднее за все голоса по данному посту.

```
post.Rating = post.Votes.Average(x=>x.Vote);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70009/discussion-on-answer-by---asp-net-mvc-5--).